# Why does this computed property fail to change in my Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am making the transition from Vue's Options API to the *Composition API* and for this purpose, I have put together a small Todo App.

In `App.vue` I have:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ErrorMessage
      v-if="!isValid"
      message="The todo body has to be at least 3 characters long"
    />

    <SuccessMessage v-if="allDone" message="You can relex! :)" />

    <p>{{ allDone }}</p>

    <div class="card">
      <Header />
      <List
        :todos="todos"
        @delete-todo="deleteTodo"
        @toggle-todo="toggleTodo"
      />
      <AddTodo @add-todo="addTodo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
import ErrorMessage from './components/ErrorMessage.vue';
import SuccessMessage from './components/SuccessMessage.vue';
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import List from './components/List.vue';
import AddTodo from './components/Add.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    ErrorMessage,
    SuccessMessage,
    Header,
    List,
    AddTodo,
  },

  setup() {
    const todos = ref([]);
    const isValid = ref(true);
    const allDone = ref(false);

    return { todos, isValid, allDone };
  },

  methods: {
    toggleTodo: function (index) {
      this.todos[index].done = !this.todos[index].done;
    },
    deleteTodo: function (index) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        this.todos.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    addTodo: function (text) {
      let newTodo = {
        done: false,
        text: text,
      };

      if (text.length > 2) {
        this.isValid = true;
        this.todos.push(newTodo);
      } else {
        this.isValid = false;
      }
    },
  },

  computed: {
    allDone: function () {
      // Check if there are todos and
      // If all of them are done
      let undoneTodos = this.todos.filter((todo) => todo.done === false);
      return this.todos.length && !undoneTodos.length;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I try to use the computed property `allDone` to check if there are todos and all of them are done, in which case I try to display a success message ("You can relax!") in an alert component.

However, the *initial value* of the `allDone` variable does not change when the conditions are met for it to change.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `allDone` from the return of the setup function, the ref will overshadow the computed property.

Alternatively, declare it as a computed property in setup and remove it from the computed option:

```
setup(){
  const todos = ref([])
  const allDone = computed(() => todos.value.length > 0 && todos.value.every(todo => todo.done))
  ...
  return {todos, allDone, ...}
}
```